# Login page not redirecting to home page on successful login

Tags: reactjs, authentication, aws-amplify

I'm using aws amplify for authentication.
On clicking login Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser() is returning true but page is redirecting to home page ,on clicking refresh it redirects to home page and works fine.

Here's the code

Home.js

```
function Home(props) {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState();

  async function isAuthenticated() {
    try {
      let res = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      console.log(res);
      setAuth(true);
    } catch {
      setAuth(false);
      console.log("error");
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    isAuthenticated();
  }, [auth]);

  console.log(auth);
  return false ? (
    <div className="c-app c-default-layout">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="c-wrapper">
        <Header {...props} />
        <div className="c-body">
          <Content />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the return condition is always false, so it will always redirect to '/login' page.

Considering you have `auth` instead of `false` in the return condition, the value of auth will be undefined at the first render, so it will again redirect to '/login' page.